# .htaccess Rewrite Parent Folder to Subfolder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking to rewrite the url so if someone lands on a parent folder, they will be redirected to its subfolder. http://www.domain.com/portfolio should take me to http://www.domain.com/portfolio/example

RewriteEngine is on, and there are other RewriteRules in the file, which are working. I have tried the following rewrites, but none perform the redirect:

```
 RewriteRule ^/portfolio/(.*)$ /portfolio/example/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

and

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com/portfolio$
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$ portfolio/example[L,QSA]
```

and

```
 RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*) http://www.domain.com/portfolio/example/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

and

```
 RewriteRule ^portfolio$ http://www.domain.com/portfolio/example[R=301,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*) http://www.domain.com/portfolio/example$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

What is the proper syntax for rewriting a url so that if a visitor lands on the parent portfolio folder, they go to the portfolio/example subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^portfolio(/(?!example).*|)$ /portfolio/example$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: There was already a "RewriteEngine on" in the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> section of the root .htaccess file, so I added your line right after it. "On" is all lowercase, though. Is it case sensitive? The rewrite did not work. I also added your code as-is outside of the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>, but it still did not work. Do I need to restart Apache?

Comment: This rule worked in my testing as the only rule in my .htaccess.. Make sure to place it in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess file`.

Comment: Thanks, there must be a conflict with the "Drupalized" .htaccess file that is not getting it to work.

Comment: I did more testing, and see that http://www.domain.com/portfolio/someurl does redirect me to http://www.domain.com/portfolio/example/someurl, however http://www.domain.com/portfolio does not redirect me to http://www.domain.com/portfolio/example

Comment: Can .htaccess check to see if the url ends with portfolio and redirect to the portfolio\example folder if it does?